# What does ^ do?

Tags: go, operators

I hope this question is not *too* stupid... I have no idea what the `^` operator does in Go, e.g.

`a := 3^500`

At first I thought it must be `pow` but it most certainly is not. It's not `mod` (%) either.

I've tried looking through the doc and searching on Google, but unfortunately Google doesn't think `^` is a search term.

Comment: For future reference the `^` operator is known as the caret. You can Google this. You'll also probably want to use "Golang" instead of "Go" too :)

Comment: Just to be sure, you didn't really see `3^500` ? This wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Actually I saw `hash ^= uint32(c)`

Comment: If you don't know something about Go syntax, have a look at the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec). It clears up most questions.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR This is where google takes me now.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As in most languages, the *caret* operator is a bitwise XOR. You use it on integers.

[Relevant Golang documentation](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators)

[Wikipedia on the bitwise xor :](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR)

> A bitwise XOR takes two bit patterns of equal length and performs the
>   logical exclusive OR operation on each pair of corresponding bits. The
>   result in each position is 1 if only the first bit is 1 or only the
>   second bit is 1, but will be 0 if both are 0 or both are 1. In this we
>   perform the comparison of two bits, being 1 if the two bits are
>   different, and 0 if they are the same
>
> The bitwise XOR may be used to invert selected bits in a register
>   (also called toggle or flip). Any bit may be toggled by XORing it with
>   1. For example, given the bit pattern 0010 (decimal 2) the second and fourth bits may be toggled by a bitwise XOR with a bit pattern
>   containing 1 in the second and fourth positions:

```
     0010 (decimal 2)
 XOR 1010 (decimal 10)
   = 1000 (decimal 8)
```

> This technique may be used to manipulate bit patterns representing sets of
>   Boolean states.

Adding the comment from @karmakaze to this answer for more helpful info:

> Also as a unary operator, it's bitwise not. e.g. `^uint(0)` results in the `uint` value `0xffffffff` for 32-bit machine and longer for a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Also as a unary operator it's bitwise not. e.g. `^uint(0)` results in the uint value `0xffffffff` for 32-bit machine and longer for 64-bit machine.

Comment: @karmakaze you should edit/improve the answer by appending your comment.